# How to keep only the numbers with 3 digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to use regex to keep only number with 3 digits in a string.

inputs

```
'1 12 123 1234'
```

expected output:

```
'123'
```

I tired this to remove number with more 3 digits

```py
re.sub("\d{4}", '', '1 12 123 1234')
```

but I don't know how to remove number with less than 3 digits.

Comment: Just use `re.findall(r'\b\d{3,}', s)`

Comment: Instead of trying to remove everything that has the wrong number of digits, why not just try to *find* everything that has the *correct* number of digits?

Comment: `re.findall(r"(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)", s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why regex? Lots of stuff where people want to use regex can be done with simple string operations.

In your case:

```py
s = '1 12 123 1234'
s = " ".join(elem for elem in s.split() if len(elem)==3)
```

`split()` without arguments splits by spaces, so you have a list of strings with numbers

`if len(elem)==3` in comprehension filters only what you need

`" ".join` joins the strings back with space between them

---

More complex example:

```
>>> s = "123 2 345 1 21 1234 456 23"
>>> s = " ".join(elem for elem in s.split() if len(elem)==3)
>>> s
'123 345 456'
```